# i want to create a search in django which have order by istartswith first than icontains

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-database

```
def autocomplete(request):
    template_name='searchresults.html'
    if 'term' in request.GET:
        qs=Post.objects.filter(Q(title__istartswith=request.GET.get('term'))|Q(content__icontains=request.GET.get('term')))
        titles=list()
        for post in qs:
            titles.append(post.title)
        return JsonResponse(titles, safe=False)
    return render(request, template_name)
```

How can I can order them ins such a way that if it begins with term order it as first and the one that contains it but does not begin with it as second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [**`.union(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#union):

```
term = request.GET.get('term')

qs = Post.objects.filter(
    title__istartswith=term
).union(Post.objects.filter(
    content__icontains=term
))
```

or with an [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

term = request.GET.get('term')

qs = Post.objects.filter(
    Q(title__istartswith=term) | Q(content__icontains=term)
).annotate(
    is_start=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(title__istartswith=term),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
).order_by('-is_start')
```

Comment: appreciated your answer but i am getting this error when i use your method raise DatabaseError('ORDER BY not allowed in subqueries of compound statements.') can you please help me out?

Comment: @ZahidWadiwale: did you add extra `.order_by`s, or did you use `ordering` in the `Meta` of the model?

Comment: yes i did used meta in models.py as subclass of post anyway to get out with it?

Comment: @ZahidWadiwale: then you can use an annotation.